# NO_PUBKEY error when trying to run "sudo apt update"

Tags: command-line, apt, gnupg

I was trying to install Sublime Text from the terminal. I followed [these steps](https://linuxhint.com/install_sublime_text3_ubuntu/).
I didn't use the update command because I already ran it a day earlier, and started with the second step. Then I started having errors, so this time I also ran the `sudo apt-get update command`, but now it's showing me this error message.

[image: the error]

Comment: Please do not include terminal input as a link to a graphic. Instead, copy paste the text of the terminal in your question, and format it as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 1):

You did not properly add the GPG key of the repository you have added. Go to step 3 of the link you provided, and try again:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```